# Remove first element from double pointer char array

Tags: c

Been trying to remove the first element from a double pointer `char` array but i keep getting errors.

The input into the `argv` is from the keyboard using:
`argv` is defined in `main` as

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    if(!fgets(*argv, 64, stdin))
        return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        j = 0;      
        while(j < strlen(*argv) - 1)
        {
            if(j == 0)
                strcpy(argv + j, argv + j + 1);
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   22 |             {   if(j == 0) strcpy(argv + j, argv + j + 1);
      |                                             ~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                                      |
      |                                                      char **
```

Comment: Why are you reading a string into `argv`? You can read it into a locally defined char array.

Comment: What "errors" are you getting? Does your code not compile? Are you getting error messages from the compiler? Or is the run-time behavior of your program not what you want?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani: I have reverted your edit, because by fixing OP's code you may have destroyed evidence of what is wrong in OP's code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, I think the code has many issues besides of its compile issues. I just want to make it compile-able.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani: If OP is asking about why their code does not compile (which now seems to be the case), then it is not helpful for a third party to edit the code in the question to make it compilable. However, I don't blame you for doing this, because at the time, it was unclear what OP was asking about, and you were only trying to help.

Comment: I have also tried this: if(j == 0) strcpy(*argv, *(argv)+1); and it removes first element but if i have "a" "b" "c" elements, it prints b c c instead of b c

Comment: @Erica: If you want to add general information about the question, then please [edit] the question instead of using the comments section for this. The comments section should only be used to respond to other people's comments.

Comment: I wrote an answer that I hope can address the issue based on what I understand. Please correct me if I understand something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many compile issues, first you need to define variable `j` and also using correct braces as follow:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(!fgets(*argv, 64, stdin))
        return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while(j < strlen(*argv) - 1)
        {
            if(j == 0)
                strcpy(argv + j, argv + j + 1);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I am strongly against using `argv` for reading a string because you don't know anything about its size in memory. Also, when you are using the `strcpy` you must pay attention to the sizes, the destination string should have at least the size of the source.

`strlen` only works on strings which means `char *` so using it on `char **` is meaningless. The following code copies each string into the left item which I think very similar to what you want to do but please note that string size is very important and `strcpy` can cause issue.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int LEN = 255;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int n = 3;

  // allocate memory for storing strings
  char **strings = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

  // reading strings from user
  // and store them
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strings[i] = malloc(LEN * sizeof(char));

    // reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s
    fgets(strings[i], LEN, stdin);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    // here we consider all the strings has the max size as LEN
    // so this copy does not cause error.
    strcpy(strings[i], strings[i + 1]);
  }
  free(strings[n - 1]);

  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    printf("[%d] %s", i, strings[i]);
  }
}
```

Also, you can use the non-dynamic way as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 255
#define N 3

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char strings[N][LEN];

  // reading strings from user
  // and store them
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s
    fgets(strings[i], LEN, stdin);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    // here we consider all the strings has the max size as LEN
    // so this copy does not cause error.
    strcpy(strings[i], strings[i + 1]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    printf("[%d] %s", i, strings[i]);
  }
}
```

Both programs have the following behavior:

```
Parham
Ali
Hassan
[0] Ali
[1] Hassan
```

Comment: Why are you limiting the final loop to `n - 1` iterations instead of `n` iterations? I understand why you are limiting the loop beforehand to `n - 1` iterations, but I see no reason to limit the final loop to `n - 1` iterations.

Comment: You don't free any of the memory you allocate with `malloc`.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory allocation (i.e. `malloc`) for allocating a memory for the strings. Dynamic memory allocation is slower and is more complicated, because it requires you to call `free` afterwards. Why not simply use a 2D array, like this: `char strings[3][255];`?

Comment: Yes, I will add the non-dynamic way too. Also, I will free up the memory.

Comment: I limited the loop to n - 1 because I am using i + 1 so in the last iteration it will use invalid memory in case of using n

Comment: @ParhamAlvani: You are not using `i + 1` in the final loop. Why don't you also want to print `string[2]` to show the entire content of the 2D array?

Comment: In the final loop I assume that we removed an string so I don't print the last string.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani: Ah, yes, you are right. OP stated that they want to "remove" the element, so it is appropriate to not print the entire array.